# I'm using .NET 4.5 version of Entity Framework. If I import Entity Framework 5.0 Nuget package, will I have any performance improvements?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework

I have read a lot of articles about Entity Framework performance. [This one for instance](http://devproconnections.com/entity-framework/improve-performance-entity-framework-5). They all say Entity Framework 5.0 has performance improvements.

What bugs me is that I don't quite understand the separation Microsoft did on the "part" of EntityFramework that actually comes with .NET framework and the part is distributed as a Nuget package.

If I keep using the same classes as  am using now and I don't change anything in my code, it doesn't make any sense for me that just importing 5.0 assemblies is going the have any impact in my software. Unless, of course, that I start using different classes and different extension methods.

My scenario: I use .NET 4.5 EntityFramework with ObjectContext, not DbContext. Will I benefit from using 5.0 in the performance standpoint? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not relay that performance with EF update will be by you greater. If you are using ObjectContext may be a little bit, because of expressions/queries. Do you need to do it for a couple of ms, is up to you.

But comparing prec-ompiled and not pre-compiled queries, I am sure that it's dealing about a couple of ms.

When you have performance problems in your application, may be better to fix it reviewing and refactoring design and architecture. Look at how much data you grab from DB, N+1 issues. And as a first, locate situations with performance problems.