# Entity Framework is taking 3 seconds to execute the simplest query I've seen in my life for the first time. It becomes instantaneous thereafter

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework 4.5 with Object Context. My model has around 200 entities type. The first time I make a ridiculous query in a 10 records database that returns 1 record, it will take 3 seconds. From then on, not only this query, but all will become instant. If I close IISExpress and open it again. The first time will be very slow again.

There must be something I can do with Entity Framework. [I've think of pregenerating views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060728/pre-generating-views-to-improve-performance-still-have-any-impact-in-net-4-5-en) or [upgrading to Entity Framework 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060305/im-using-net-4-5-version-of-entity-framework-if-i-import-entity-framework-5-0), but I'm not really sure this will help.

Any idea?

**EDIT**
Queries executed directly in Management Studio are always fast. The query is very simple. I just get a user by username, and the table has like.. 10 records.  Debug or release don't make much difference.

Comment: what is the query ? What happens when you run the simple query directly against the DB ? If you have used the profiler what does that tell you when you run the query for the first and second time ?

Comment: Is it slow when the debugger is not attached and built in release mode too?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I updated the question with additional information.

Comment: So, it runs fine after the first call. Shouldn't you spend your time optimizing the common case - where it's not the first call? (Unless you plan for your system to be continually crashing IIS or restarting, such that the first call *is* the common case)

Comment: What is the exact query that is run against Sql?  It's entirely possible for a simple-seeming query in EF to generate complex Sql - it's worth confirming that it's as simple as you think.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known "issue".  I put that in quotes because it's an issue for you and me, but Microsoft considers it normal and not a problem.  [This MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows the performance costs of various parts of EF.

There are already [many, many, many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=entity%20framework%20slow%20first%20time) questions on SO about this.  I would suggest exploring some of them.  There was a particular question a year or two ago in which a pretty detailed analysis of the problem was done by multiple people, but I can't seem to find it right now.

In particular this is very slow with large models and EDMX files, converting to a code first model could help.

Answer (score 1):

The delay is due to the time Entity Framework takes to fire up.

see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507067/entity-framework-codefirst-delay-experienced/15507195#15507195) for more info